# How do I use trans_new to shift a scale by a constant in ggplot2 without messing up the tick labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

Let's say I have a continuous x-axis, and I want to add a constant value to each tickmark label. For example

```
ggplot(data=warpbreaks,aes(x=breaks,y=replicate)) + geom_point()
```

...will have tickmarks at 20, 40, and 60. What if I want those tickmarks to instead read 40, 60, and 80 *without* altering the rest of the plot? I tried this:

```
ggplot(data=warpbreaks,aes(x=breaks,y=replicate)) + geom_point() + 
scale_x_continuous(trans=trans_new("shift",function(x) x+20,identity))
```

That shifted the tickmarks by the appropriate amount but also deleted the leftmost one. If I use `x+40` instead then two tickmarks get omitted from the left side leaving only one. If I do `x+10` then all of them are shifted over by that amount and none of them are omitted. What's going on? How can I reliably shift the x values?

Motivation: when I fit regression models I usually center the numeric predictor variables (unless they actually encompass zero) to avoid absurd/misleading main effects estimates outside the support range of the data. However, when I plot the data and/or fitted values I want to return them to the original, non-centered scale.

Comment: I'm not quite sure this will work the way you want in your motivation example, but `ggplot(data=warpbreaks,aes(x=breaks,y=wool)) + geom_point() + scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) x+20)` does what you are asking.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first option is proposed by @mnel:

```
ggplot(data=warpbreaks,aes(x=breaks,y=wool)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels=function(x) x+20)
```

Note that you can change the data "locally" (inside a ggplot call), so here's another option:

```
ggplot(data=warpbreaks,aes(x=breaks+20,y=wool)) + geom_point()
```

In that case, no tinkering with scales is required.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you both. @mnel, this does indeed work for my purposes. I also thought of one more (less elegant) way: after the ggplot object is created, `myplot <- ggplot(data=warpbreaks,aes(x=breaks,y=wool))+geom_point()`, manually offsetting the actual variable: myplot$data$breaks<-myplot$data$breaks+20.